# Incorrect time shown in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, timezone

I see that the time in my Ubuntu 20.04 (12:40 PM) is different from my wall clock and also the [www.timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com) web site (12:20 PM). As you can see int he picture, the time zones are correct. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `timedatectl` command?

Comment: Check that `systemd-timesyncd` is running... Check with the commands `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` (must be **Active: active (running)**) and `journalctl -b -u systemd-timesyncd.service` (should show time synchronization status).

Answer (score 0):

1. step list time zone

   ```
   timedatectl list-timezones
   ```
2. Set its time zone

   ```
   sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/La_Paz
   ```