# No time synchronization on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sync, time

the time-synchronization does not work on my Ubuntu 20.04 (it always shows a time two hours ahead of the actual time). I have tried to follow the hints [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-sync-time-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287055/incorrect-time-shown-in-20-04) but without success.

I have already installed `ntp`, but when I run

```
timedatectl set-ntp on
```

in the terminal I get the output:

```
Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported
```

It drives me crazy because even when I set the time manually, it reverts to the old (and wrong) setting after restart.

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have possibly selected wrong time zone. Is this a desktop or a server system? Please, remove `ntp` and [edit] your question by adding the output of `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`.

Comment: Are you dual booting or is Ubuntu the only installed OS?

Answer (score 4):

You have probably selected wrong time zone.

Also, if the system is not going to be used as a time server, the `ntp` daemon is *not* recommended in recent versions of Ubuntu. Instead, `systemd-timesyncd` daemon should be used.

Please,

1. Run `sudo apt remove ntp` to remove `ntp`.
2. Run `sudo apt install --reinstall systemd-timesyncd` to refresh `systemd-timesyncd`s installation.
3. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to select the correct time zone.
4. Afterwards, run `cat /etc/timezone` to check it.
5. Run, `timedatectl status` to check that:

   ```
   System clock synchronized: yes
                 NTP service: active
             RTC in local TZ: no
   ```

   **Note:** If you are not dual booting (with Windows) you should set the hardware clock to UTC (i.e., `RTC in local TZ: no` in the above output), using the command `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0 --adjust-system-clock`. For more information see this:
   [How to tell Ubuntu that hardware clock is local time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946516/how-to-tell-ubuntu-that-hardware-clock-is-local-time)
6. Run, `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` to check that `systemd-timesyncd` daemon is:

   ```
   Active: active (running) since ...
   ```
7. If it is not active, run `systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd` to enable it and `systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd` to start it.
8. If you get errors in the above commands, you may need to run:

   ```
   $ timedatectl set-ntp false
   $ ## set approximate time manually using the `date` command.
   $ timedatectl set-ntp true
   ```

   and retry from step 5.
9. Reboot system and check once more.

Comment: removing `systemd-timesyncd` uninstalls hundreds of packages that depend on it, according to `apt -s remove` on my system. Such drastic changes are very unlikely to be reversible. I am going to edit your answer to use the handy `--reinstall` flag instead.